# Ideas to optimize the time complexity of the program

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have encountered a programming problem, and I have been stuck on it for quite sometime now. I realise that I only started learning algorithms and data structures, but really need some ideas from more experienced folk.

The program recieves an input as txt file, with time intervals (start, stop). It is a car delivery service. Input looks like this:
4 (number of calls for cars)
08:00:00 11:00:00 (call 1 start:finish)
09:00:00 10:00:00 (call 2 start:finish)
10:00:00 11:10:00 (call 2 start:finish)
10:59:59 13:00:00 (call 2 start:finish)

First number is the number of deliveries, the second until the last, time intervals. When car takes a call it is not available until the 'finish' time, so in case we have another call prior to the first car's completion, we have to send another one.

My goal is to find the minimum required number of cars to complete all calls.

For the example above, that one would be 3. Car can start another call straight after it finished the pervious one, so it is possible to finish at 10:00:00 and start another call at 10:00:00.

So the code below, is obviously clumsy and not efficient enough. It gives right solutions, but fails on time complexity for the large data sets, any help with optimising this program?

```
input_file = open('input1.txt')

calls = [x.split() for x in input_file.readlines()[1:]]
calls.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
time_available = [x[1] for x in calls]

for start, stop in calls:
    for i in time_available:
        if start >= i:
            time_available.remove(i)
            break

print(len(time_available))
```

This solution manages to give me all correct answers, including the black box grader I am checking it in, but though it is fine with memory it fails with time complexity. My guess that it has something to do with nested for loops.

P.S. I need to sort the input time intervals, because other tests seem to require it.
P.P.S other example:
10
08:00:00 11:00:00
08:00:00 11:00:00
08:00:00 11:00:00
08:00:00 11:00:00
08:00:00 11:00:00
12:00:00 12:00:01
12:00:00 23:59:59
12:00:00 13:00:01
13:00:00 13:00:01
13:00:00 13:00:01
answer:5

Comment: `any help with optimising this program?` this implies that your code is already working. StackOverflow is for questions about non-working code. You might be able to formulate a new post that fits within the rules of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and try asking there for help, since that seems like a more appropriate place.

Comment: @RandomDavis I guess you might be right, but at the same time, even though the code is functioning, it clearly doesn't meet the requirements. Still, thank you for the reply and direction, I will sure check it!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your task is essentially to find out how many time intervals overlap at most? You will always need as many cars. If yes, I think you can do that in `O(n)` with a sliding window approach

Comment: @RandomDavis I think this question is very much on-topic as per the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (Second bullet point).

Comment: Pretty common question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-platforms-required-railwaybus-station/

Answer (score 0):

With start and end times in sorted order, accumulate a value of 1 for starts and -1 for ends and the maximum (high water mark) will be your answer:

```
from itertools import accumulate

calls = [("08:00:00","11:00:00"),
         ("08:00:00","11:00:00"),
         ("08:00:00","11:00:00"),
         ("08:00:00","11:00:00"),
         ("08:00:00","11:00:00"),
         ("12:00:00","12:00:01"),
         ("12:00:00","23:59:59"),
         ("12:00:00","13:00:01"),
         ("13:00:00","13:00:01"),
         ("13:00:00","13:00:01")]

startends = [ (time,ss) for s,e in calls for (time,ss) in ((s,1),(e,-1)) ]
levels    = [ lv for _,lv in sorted(startends) ]
maxCars   = max(accumulate(levels))

print(maxCars) # 5
```

*This is similar to counting the levels of nested parentheses. You go up one level when you open a parenthesis (i.e. start a call) and subtract 1 when you close a parenthesis (i.e. end a call).  The highest level of opened parenthesis is like the number of cars simultaneously on calls.*

If you're starting form a string that you need to manually split, you can build the `startends` list like this:

```
line = "10 08:00:00 11:00:00 08:00:00 11:00:00 08:00:00 11:00:00 08:00:00 11:00:00 08:00:00 11:00:00 12:00:00 12:00:01 12:00:00 23:59:59 12:00:00 13:00:01 13:00:00 13:00:01 13:00:00 13:00:01"
startends = [ (time,(-1)**i) for i,time in enumerate(line.split()[1:]) ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am just wondering, I was using list comprehension to form list of lists with input data:

calls = [x.split() for x in input_file.readlines()[1:]]

Is there any particular reason, you are using list of tuples? Or can be the list comprehension I showed be modified?

Comment: I didn't have any usable input data so I made up something to illustrate the approach.  If you have your starts and ends in a different structure, you will need to transpose them into a sortable pair combining the time and the +1 / -1 increments (i.e. the startends list)

Comment: I have a txt file where every line starts with n/ line. So I open it (input_file = open('input.txt')). Then I use 'calls = [x.split() for x in (input_file.readlines())]'.